# Python 3.0 RPMs for CentOS 5 (RHEL 5)

Tags: centos, python, rhel5, rpm

Where is the best repository you use to obtain RPMs for Python 3.0 which are well maintained?

Comment: I don't think you'll find that easily. It's not even easy to find decent Python 2.5 packages for CentOS 5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try package from ActiveState [http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads/). It doesn't depend on package manager (just unpack and run "install.sh").

Or you can compile Python and create package by yourself

Here is how to create RPM by yourself:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-rpm1
- http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/RPM-HOWTO/

Here is how you can compile it:

```
./configure
make
make test
sudo make install    # or "make altinstall"
```

Comment: When you said "create package by yourself," I thought you were going to point to an automated way to generate python packages. Instead you're just pointing to a generic RPM howto. Duh.

Comment: This works for me.

Comment: Note that ActivePython now comes with PyPM (only 2.6 at the moment; but 2.7 and 3.1 are planned). http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/pypm.html

Comment: While the links above will tell you how to create RPM packages, do bear in mind that the python RPM packages that do exist for RHEL/CentOS 5, apply several patches to make Python play nicer with these systems.  I would recommend looking at the SPEC file for the EPEL python26 package as a starting point for packaging Python 3 (http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/SRPMS/repoview/python26.html).

Answer (score 1):

Please note that many of the tools redhat ships rely on python, so you're probably better off building from source and installing in /usr/local/ or using a bleeding edge release like Fedora 11.

Comment: Not even Fedora 11 ships with Python 3 packages by default yet.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt as there are any. I have always been quite successful installing python 3000 from source and running it so you would probably be ok doing that its quite nice and easy - that way you can also run multiple versions of python at the same time in order to maintain compatibility with any older scripts you may be running. Just remember that centos isn't really designed for new and emerging technologies so it will be a long time before python 3 comes into the official repos.

Answer (score 0):

I find the openSUSE build page very useful.

One of the neat things Novell got when they bought SUSE was the Autobuild model.  I am told it is a reasonably large cluster of devices (in the hundreds, last I asked) that recompiles most anything for all the platforms they officially support.  (x86, x86_64, IA64, IBM mainframe hardware, PowerPC, etc).

They extended Autobuild to also build most packages for most OS's!!

http://software.opensuse.org/search

I see lots of Python packages for RHEL 5, but I did not spend the time to see if 3.0 is in there as I could not quite figure out the search fast enough.

Since you are motivated, you can spend more time on it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
rpmbuild --rebuild http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/linux/development/source/SRPMS/python-2.6-7.fc11.src.rpm
```

if you really want 3.0 (which is almost broken because a bottleneck in io) just change .spec file

Comment: Unfortunately that's going to replace the native Python and will cause problem with all its libs, that are going to have to be recompiled.
What would be more useful would be a way to have several major versions alongside, and be able to use /etc/alternatives, etc

Answer (score 0):

well you can always build your own:

http://www.grenadepod.com/2009/12/26/building-python-2-6-4-rpm-for-centos-5-4/

as the saying goes - if you want to have something done properly, do it yourself... :)